# Google Play service (ads) error

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I've got problem with integrate google play service ad with my layout. I did all I saw in the web, nothing worked for me.

Note: "XXX" or "X" are just for hiding some information.

This is my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height=
    "wrap_content" android:gravity="center">
     <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff000000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXX" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/timetable" android:choiceMode="none"
        android:layout_width="230px" android:layout_height="205px"
        android:padding="5dip" />
    <TextView style="@style/finePrint" android:id="@+id/notes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and I did what to do in manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="XXX"
    android:versionCode="X"
    android:versionName="x" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="4" />

    <supports-screens />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:description="@string/description"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/DialogTheme" >

       <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".XXX"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|locale"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >



            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <receiver android:name=".receiver.StartNotificationReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".receiver.ClickNotificationReceiver" />
        <receiver android:name=".receiver.ClearNotificationReceiver" />

        <service android:name=".service.FillDailyTimetableService" />
        <service android:name=".service.StartNotificationService" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".widget.TimetableWidgetProvider"
            android:label="@string/adhan_timetable" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_timetable" />
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".widget.NextNotificationWidgetProvider"
            android:label="@string/XXX" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_next_notification" />
               <!-- Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->


        </receiver>
         <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

but when I try to lunch the application, it doesn't "Unfortunately, XXX has stopped"

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To use AdMob, you need to sign up for an account. An AdMob account is made up of one AdSense account and one AdWords account. During the sign-up process, google review your current AdSense and AdWords accounts or help you create new ones. Then, google connect them to create your new AdMob account.
[create your own admob account](https://apps.admob.com/admob/signup) or [read this](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2784575?hl=en)

[AdMob for Android](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) This guide will show you how to integrate the Google Mobile Ads SDK into a brand new app and use it to display a simple banner ad

Comment: I saw it, and did the same, it does not work, probably its the layout, tried many things but didn't work

Comment: Dis you checked other required things that needs to be added like configuring Gradle, adding logic in java class, giving an Ad Unit id.. check this list https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: I just did that, but I'm not an Android studio user, I use eclipse